# How to migrate part of an SVN repository?

Tags: migration, svn

How do you migrate a *part* of an SVN repository into a new repository?

To migrate the contents of a *complete* SVN repository into a new repository, one has to dump the old repository first:

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/repository > repository-name.dmp
```

and then load it into the new one using `svnadmin load`.

But I'm not sure how to just migrate a part. Do I still have to dump the whole thing? Do I grep for the part that I want?

To just dump `myproject`, I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/repository/myproject
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This probably belongs over on http://www.stackoverflow.com/ as they're usually far more experienced than us at using SVN. If others agree, we will move it automatically for you, so no need to re-post.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to pull over part of the repository, a particular subdirectory. You'll first need to dump the entire repository, run svndumpfilter to include that directory, and finally load things into a clean repository.

Lets say you want to move directory Calc, you would do:

```
svnadmin dump repos > dumpfile
cat dumpfile | svndumpfilter include Calc > dumpfile-Calc
```

Then to load the Calc directory back properly you would do:

```
svnadmin create newrepos
svnadmin load Calc < dumpfile-Calc
```

This is taken and slightly modified from the docs: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch05s03.html

Comment: This is the exact way to do this. There is something about renumbering revision numbers if I recall correctly, but it should be mentioned in the documentation you linked to.

Comment: only comment would be to this answer is that in the last line, you mention "Calc" but in the line above, you have "newrepos" .. chose one or the other : )

Answer (score 0):

When I wanted to do this, I simply did an `svnadmin dump` and an `svnadmin load`, the same as you did, then I deleted everything else out of the repo.

The repo was only 3gb in size, so it wasn't such a huge deal, and for security it's not so good as you can obviously undo the deletes by rolling back, but it achieved the same thing, because I couldn't find a way to do it, with keeping the revision history.

Comment: As CaCl has pointed out, you can use svndumpfilter to filter irrelevant revisions out of the dump.